# can you help me understand the most common scenarios for writing a custom hook?

Tags: reactjs

My understanding is that a custom hook is used as a wrapper for components with cross-cutting concerns.  But another key criteria for custom hooks is that they leverage useState().  Is my understanding correct that a function is not a custom hook unless it uses useState()?

It feels a bit counterintuitive to traditional design principles to write a custom hook that maintains its own state.  A more service-oriented stateless architecture has historically been favored for isolation and decoupling.

I mean sure the useSelector() hook makes absolute sense when leveraging Redux because global state management is Redux's dedicated job.  But what would be the most compelling scenarios in which a developer should write a custom hook for an app outside the context of Redux or similar global state management tool?

Are there any specific common scenarios that you would mention if asked what the most compelling drivers would be for this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the hook is not for sharing the state. It uses for sharing logic(statefull).
The only required thing to make a custom hook is the name of the function should start with `use` and nothing else.
Rest of the answers you could find here. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks